# Style changing with JS not responding

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to change style to a component by "classList.add" but for some reasons it is working for the first two element and for all the rest is taking the new class.
Is there any reason why this is happening and how I can work around to fix this issue?
Basically a button in the page has opacity: 0.3, by selecting and answer the button will become active from disable and the opacity should be 1

Thanks
Here my example:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < option.length; i++) {

  [].forEach.call(opts, (el) => {
    el.addEventListener("click", btnClick, false);
  });
  option[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    // console.log(option[i])
    // console.log('CLICKED') // click on answer
    move.classList.add("active");
    nextSecond.classList.add("active");
    nextThird.classList.add("active");
    nextFour.classList.add("active");
    nextFive.classList.add("active");
    nextSix.classList.add("active");
    nextSeven.classList.add("active");
  });
}

function btnClick() {
  [].forEach.call(opts, (el) => {
    if (el !== this) el.classList.remove("selected");
  });
  this.classList.add("selected");
  $(".next").removeAttr("disabled");
  $(".nextSecond").removeAttr("disabled");
  $(".nextThird").removeAttr("disabled");
  $(".nextFour").removeAttr("disabled");
  $(".nextFive").removeAttr("disabled");
  $(".nextSix").removeAttr("disabled");
  $(".nextSeven").removeAttr("disabled");
}
```

```css
.btn {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 42px;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  color: #4BA21C;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 220px;
  border-radius: 23px;
  border: 2px solid #4BA21C;
  height: 46px;
  background-color: white;
  &.btn-left {
    margin-left: -56px;
  }
  &:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  &.back,
  &.next,
  &.nextSecond,
  &.nextThird.ans.active,
  &.nextFour,
  &.nextFive,
  &.nextSix,
  &.nextSeven {
    width: 116px;
  }
  &.back {
    color: #5C5C5C;
    border: 2px solid #5C5C5C;
    background-color: white;
  }
  &.next,
  &.nextSecond,
  &.nextThird,
  &.nextFour,
  &.nextFive,
  &.nextSix,
  &.nextSeven {
    margin-right: 33px;
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  &.nextFour,
  &.nextFive,
  &.nextSix {
    margin-right: -14px;
  }
}

.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Question Page 3 -->

<div class="questionsPageThree hide">
  <p class="number">3/7</p>
  <div class="second">
    <h1>
      <span>Info</span>mentum
    </h1>
    <p class="hero">
      <span class="start">
                &gt;
            </span> Making change work</p>
  </div>

  <div class="q">
    <div class="left">
      <h2 class="three">3. Do you have someone who you feel comfortable sharing your feelings with?</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="opt">
      <button class="options choosen" type="submit" value="3">
              &check; Yes

            </button>
      <button class="options choosen" type="submit" value="0">
              &#120 No

            </button>
    </div>

    <div class="right">
      <div class="image-right question3"></div>
    </div>
    <section class="q1">
      <button class="btn btn-left back" value="BACK" type="button">
                BACK
            </button>
      <button class="btn btn-right nextThird ans" value="NEXT" type="button" disabled="disabled">
                NEXT
            </button>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Question Page 4 -->

<div class="questionsPageFour hide">
  <p class="number">4/7</p>
  <div class="second">
    <h1>
      <span>Info</span>mentum
    </h1>
    <p class="hero">
      <span class="start">
                &gt;
            </span> Making change work</p>
  </div>

  <div class="q">
    <div class="left">
      <h2>4. How many times this week would you say you felt stressed to the point of worry?</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="opt">
      <button class="options choosen" type="submit" value="3">
                <h4> 0</h4>
                <h6>TIMES</h6>
            </button>
      <button class="options choosen" type="submit" value="0">
                <h4>1 - 2</h4>
                <h6>TIMES</h6>
            </button>
      <button class="options choosen" type="submit" value="-2">
                <h4>3 + </h4>
                <h6>TIMES</h6>
            </button>
    </div>

    <div class="right">
      <div class="image-right question4"></div>
    </div>
    <section class="q1">
      <button class="btn btn-left back" value="BACK" type="button">
                BACK
            </button>
      <button class="btn btn-right nextFour ans" value="NEXT" type="button" disabled="disabled">
                NEXT
            </button>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>

javascript html jquery css class
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], preferably in the form of a Stack Snippet.

Comment: What is `opts`?

Comment: are my option answers.

Comment: Can you add the HTML and definition of `opts`? You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: I made a snippet, so please also add JS for option, or just define it... `option is not defined`

Comment: The CSS shown is not valid CSS, but rather something like SASS or LESS. If it is important to your question, please provide the rendered CSS.

Comment: It's a bit unclear why you're mixing jQuery and native DOM methods like that; currently your code won't run because it's looking for a variable `opts` which is not defined. If it were, it would have a problem with `move`, then `nextSecond`, etc..

Comment: it is working fine for the first 3 as expected then not longer reading any property